# pyserial readline takes too long

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm having a strange problem using pyserial to comunicate to a microcontroller device of my own design.
What I wanto to do is send a command to the uC and receive and process the answer.
The problem is that when I use readline() it always returns on timeout, instead of when it detects a "\n". If I set timeout to cero, readline() returns empty.

```
import serial
import time
ser=serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate=9600
ser.timeout=5
ser.port=0
ser.open()
while True :
    cmnd=raw_input(">: ")
    if cmnd == "quit":
        break
    ser.write(cmnd+"\n") 
    ck=time.clock()
    resp=ser.readline()
    ck=time.clock()-ck;
    print ">>"+resp
    print "tiempo: "+str(ck)
```

I did find a solution of sorts: If I call time.sleep(0.1) right before calling readline(), it returns immediatelly (+ the 0.1 seconds of the sleep command). I can live with this, but I'd like to know if there is a more "elegant" solution for this problem. Here is how the code looks with the workaround:

```
import serial
import time
ser=serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate=9600
ser.timeout=5
ser.port=0
ser.open()
while True :
    cmnd=raw_input(">: ")
    if cmnd == "quit":
        break
    ser.write(cmnd+"\n") 
    ck=time.clock()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    resp=ser.readline()
    ck=time.clock()-ck;
    print ">>"+resp
    print "tiempo: "+str(ck)
```

I'm using windows 8.1 and python 2.7. Also, I'm not testing it in real hardware, but using a virtual pair of serial ports created with "Virtual Serial Ports" by HDD software and simulating the microcontroller on Proteus ISIS VSM.

Comment: What's the `_readline`?

Comment: I tried rewriting the ser.readline() function. Had the exact same results. I forgot to change it before copy+pasting here.